AsyncIOScheduler не работает на сервере
Есть бэкенд на fastapi. Использую AsyncIOScheduler для того, чтобы раз в день выполнялся парсинг сайта и удаление старых данных из базы данных. Локально всё работает, но, если развернуть бэкенд на сервере c linux, парсинг и авто удаление не выполняются.
Файл main_parsing.py
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from app.events.dao import EventsDAO
from app.events.parsing.unicorn_road.main_unicorn_parsing import parse_unicorn

scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()

scheduler.add_job(parse_unicorn, 'cron', hour=17, minute=0)
scheduler.add_job(EventsDAO.delete_past_events, 'cron', hour=17, minute=0)

main.py:
import time

from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

from app.events.parsing.main_parsing import scheduler
from app.logger import logger
from app.users.router import router as users_router
from app.events.router import router as events_router


app = FastAPI()

app.include_router(users_router)
app.include_router(events_router)

scheduler.start()


@app.on_event("shutdown")
def shutdown_event():
    scheduler.shutdown()


Что значит «не выполняется»? А что происходит вместо выполнения? Как оно «развёрнуто»?

Просто не парсит и не удаляет. В логах сейчас увидел вот такое:
backend-1 | {"timestamp": "2024-08-31T14:54:34.786747Z", "level": "INFO", "message": "Request handling time", "module": "main", "funcName": "add_process_time_header", "taskName": "Task-28", "process_time": 0.0022}
nginx-1 | 172.169.4.209 - - [31/Aug/2024:14:54:34 +0000] "GET /actuator/health HTTP/1.1" 404 22 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 zgrab/0.x"
Развёрнуто через docker compose
